# including footer.php and header.php

Tags: css, html

I have created a top bar and a bottom bar for my website's index.  I have isolated both of them in two files, the header.php, which controls the top bar and the footer.php, which controls the bottom bar.

In the index there is no problem, but if I create a new page like about.php, and I include the two php files, the top and bottom bar are moved to the right by 10px (or something like that).

In this case the page is larger, because there is this tiny blank space to the left, before the beginning of the two bars.

Here are the two files:

*Header.php*

```
<style>
.blue { background-color: #039; width: 100%; height: 15%; position: absolute; top: 0px; } 
html, body { width: 650px; background-color:#F5F5F5;}
</style>

<div class="blue">
    <h1 style="text-align: center; color:#FFFFCC ;font-family:"Times New Roman",Times,serif;">My Website</h1>
</div>
```

*Footer.php*

```
<ul id="figo">
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>


<style> 
#figo {background-color: #039; position:absolute; bottom:0px; width:100%;}
ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

li{
  float:right;
}

a{
  display:block;
  width:90px;
  color:#FFFFCC;

}
</style>
```

INDEX.PHP
Here I post the index.php

-

```
 <html> 

   <head> <title> About </title> </head> 

   <body> 



   <? include 'header.php'; ?>

   <?include 'footer.php'; ?>


   </body> 

   </html>
```

Comment: Just an observation, you should add `type="text/css"` to your `<style>` tag, like so: `<style type="text/css">`

Comment: The problem most likely has more to do with where you are placing the php includes that the files themselves. From a construction standpoint, I personally don't like littering HTML with style declarations and prefer to keep the CSS in one location. Sure makes for much easier adjustments.

Comment: can you post the HTML of the pages your including the includes on?

Comment: You should specify all your styles within the `<head>` block. Having `<style>` in your `<body>` is invalid HTML.

Comment: can we get a link to the page?

Comment: @TomS: Not if he's using [HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-style-element).

Comment: `<h1 style="text-align: center; color:#FFFFCC ;font-family:"Times New Roman",Times,serif;">My Website</h1>`. This won't work. use ' around _Times New Roman_ instead of quotation marks.

Comment: @AymanSafadi, it [defaults to `text/css` in it's absence](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#attr-style-type), but doesn't hurt to use it anyway. Thanks for pointing it out though, didn't know it wasn't required in HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

The `<style></style>` tags should only go into the `<head></head>` portion of a document. You want to avoid having any inline styles as well. Better than using `<style></style>`, you should put all the styles that are to be used by all of your pages into a single stylesheet.

I would implement a wrapper (container) and give that your page width and position relative, this will align your footer menu to the bottom of that block (assuming that's what you're trying to achieve). If not, drop the position from the container.

With all of these changes, the structure would look something like this. Keep in mind this is a very archaic design, but it should help get you started.
header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
...
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div class="blue" id="header">
        <h1>Header Content</h1>
    </div>
```

index.php/about.php/whatever.php...

```
<?php
$title = 'My About Page';
include('header.php');
?>
    <div>Your page contents</div>
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

footer.php:

```
    <div id="footer">
        <ul id="figo">
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div><!-- end "container" -->
</body>
</html>
```

/css/stylesheet.css:

```
body {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 650px;
}

.blue {
    background-color: #039;
    height: 15%;
}

#figo {
    background-color: #039;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#figo ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#figo li {
    float: right;
}

#figo a {
    display: block;
    width: 90px;
    color: #FFFFCC;
}
```

Comment: In this way, I can not work on another page that has other CSS content in the <body>. I want to have an header.php and footer.php as reference, not as the main structure of the website. They just have to build my top and bottom bar.

Comment: Your CSS *should* be in it's own stylesheet linked in the header of the page, this is a very archaic design. Even your index/about page could pass variables on to the header.php file to have it parse items such as title, extra stylesheets or javascripts.

Comment: Yes,but In the way you did, if I want to open a new page and I want to include other new css elements I am obliged to modify the header.php..

Comment: I was wondering if it was possible to create an internal css in header.php just for the top bar and the background color of body..

Comment: @EdoardoMoreni That is why I said your styles should go into a stylesheet, I have edited my answer/examples to reflect this. You should not be including styles in your individual pages, they need to go into a stylesheet and must be included as either `<style></style>` tags in the `<head></head>` or linked (as noted in my edit).

Answer (score 0):

Kill the position: absolute on your `.blue` top bar. You don't need it; since it's at the top of your HTML, it'll be at the top of the page. [The space is probably the result of the default padding on the `body`.] Try CSS like this:

```
html, body { background-color:#F5F5F5; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.blue { background-color: #039; height: 15%; }
```

To be sure, though, we'd need to see index.php and footer.php.

Why are you setting a width on the html and body elements? That's a little funky. If you want a 600px-wide content area with a gray background, create a wrapper div and apply the background to that:

```
#wrap { background: #f5f5f5; width: 600px; }

<body>
    <div id="wrap">
    <?php require "header.php"; ?>
    content here
    <?php require "footer.php"; ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

Also, `style` elements should be placed as children of the `head` element. Or, better yet, in an external stylesheet, so you separate presentation from content.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your getting the padding on the left is because you have <html> on both your header.php as well as the page you are loading the header file on.

Additionally, it would be a better practice to put header and footer into a higher level folder within your server. Then reference that file with

```
Include("../../header.php");
```

The styles being within one or two style sheets is the best way to accomplish styling as well. You would need to refer to nodes in you document by parent class and class or IDs. That would allow you to get different styles on different pages but have one style sheet.

```
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'>
         //do stuff
    </div>
</div>
```

Then style with

```
<style type='text/css'>
    .parent .child{
        cool:stuff;
    }
</style>
```

And finally, make sure the style only shows up within the <head> of the page:-)