# Hide link when on specified page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a footer file with a contact us link and copyright information. When I click the contact us link, it will go to the contact us page. I have my footer as a php file and just include in the respective page. I would like to hide the contact us link when in the contact us page. How can I go about doing this?

***footer.php***

```
<?php
    echo '<footer class="footer">
              <div class="container">
                  <p class="text-muted"><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></p>
                  <p class="text-muted"> Copyright &copy; <span id="yearfooter"> </span>. All rights reserved.</p>
              </div>
          </footer>';
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856007/how-do-i-get-the-current-page-name-if-its-not-displayed-in-the-url-when-that-pa

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will return current page URL

Comment: why you want echo the footer instead display as html tag and echo at page you include ? if change as accordingly you could use javascript or jquery to accomplish this

Comment: @theinarasu i have not try that yet. echo at caller?

Comment: @MichelleAshwini sorry its was type error , what i mean by caller , the page where you include the footer.php <?php include footer.php .. you may follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683054/including-footer-php-and-header-php

Comment: `basename(__FILE__)` gives you the current filename.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Instead of using `echo`, just write the html outside the `<?php ?>` tags and check the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and only show the link if it is not the contact page.

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/contactus.html') !== 0) { ?>
        <p class="text-muted"><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></p>
        <?php } ?>
        <p class="text-muted"> Copyright &copy; <span id="yearfooter"> </span>. All rights reserved.</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, the contact us page link is still displayed in the contactus page.

Comment: @MichelleAshwini hmm, what is the uri of the contactus page exactly? I mean everything after the domain (`.com`,`.net`, etc.).

Comment: @Andrew this cannot use if the url like http://www.example.com/some-dir/yourpage.php?q=bogus&n=10 and $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] will give you -> /some-dir/yourpage.php?q=bogus&n=10

Comment: @theinarasu I know but I figured the contactus.html page wouldn't have any query strings attached. I suppose they could check the file generating it but it could be one php file for everything.

Comment: that's why you should parse the link like i mentionned in my answer: `$page_name=preg_replace('#^(.+[\\\/])*([^\\\/]+)$#', '$2', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);`

Comment: @MichelleAshwini I made some changes to my answer. Why don't you give it a try. Now it just checks that the REQUEST_URI does not start with `/contactus.html` because there could be stuff at the end as theinarasu noted

Comment: @Andrew The contact us link is not displayed in all the pages now

Comment: @MichelleAshwini  i think this should be the answer

Comment: @MichelleAshwini Do'h! Sorry I made a simple mistake. Try it now. It should work now, hopefully.

Comment: Sorry @Andrew. Contact Us is still displayed in the contact us page.

Comment: @MichelleAshwini I just noticed in the other answer that your site is at localhost/website. In that case, you would have to change one line in the code in my answer to say `<?php if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/website/contactus.html') !== 0) { ?>`

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
$page_name=preg_replace('#^(.+[\\\/])*([^\\\/]+)$#', '$2', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
if ($page_name!="about-us.html") {
    //display your link
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try this ..

```
<footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="text-muted"><a id="a" href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></p>
            <p class="text-muted"> Copyright &copy; <span id="yearfooter"> </span>. All rights reserved.</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

and in javascript

```
     var pathname = window.location.pathname;
        var appDomainEndding = 'yourdomain.com/app/'
        if (pathname.toLowerCase().indexOf("contactus.html") > -1 || 
            pathname.indexOf(appDomainEndding, pathname.length - appDomainEndding.length) > -1)
       // add class to hide the a tag 
{
document.getElementById("a").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It still displays the contact us link tho.

Comment: @MichelleAshwini what you change appDomainEndding value ?

Comment: Since I'm deploying this in my local server currently, I put it as localhost/website/. This is where my source files are

Comment: you may remove this  pathname.indexOf(appDomainEndding, pathname.length - appDomainEndding.length) > -1 and try again

Comment: @MichelleAshwini i was updated my answer .. try again